# Abstract Algebra: need help with next step finding $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt[3]{2} ): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question asks: Compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt[3]{2} ): \mathbb{Q}] $

I've worked it to

=$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt[3]{2} ): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}): \mathbb{Q}] $

= $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt[3]{2} ): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})] * 2 $

so what is the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt[3]{2} ): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})]$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abstract Algebra, what is this even asking.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740303/abstract-algebra-what-is-this-even-asking)

Answer (score 1):

You have the following diagram of field extensions and degrees:
[image: Field extensions]

So, $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5,\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb Q]$ is a multiple of $2$, a multiple of $3$ and at most $2 \cdot 3$, so it is $6$.

Note that it follows that $x^3 - 2$ is the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ over ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt 5)$ and that $x^2 - 5$ is the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt5$ over ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},  \sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial $p$ for $\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. An obvious  candidate is the usual $p(x) =  x^3 - 2$. Prove that this is  indeed  the minimal polynomial by showing that no  polynomial of lower degree can annihilate  $\sqrt[3]{2}$. For instance, clearly no linear polynomial will.  Why can no quadratic?

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^3-2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is reducible if and only if it has a root. So suppose $(a+b\sqrt{5})^3=2$. This becomes
$$
a^3+3a^2b\sqrt{5}+15ab^2+5b^3\sqrt{5}=2
$$
and so
$$
\begin{cases}
a^3+15ab^2=2\\[4px]
3a^2b+5b^3=0
\end{cases}
$$
Can you finish?